# How to authenticate with Salesforce from Metadata API by using a .NET application

Tags: metadata-api, wsdl

I need to create an custom object using Salesforce Metadata API. For that I just created a .NET application by using Metadata wsdl. I can't find a login method in the Metadata API in order to get session Id from Salesforce. Am I need to use enterprise wsdl or partner wsdl for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. The other WSDL files don't provide a login method, as it is expected you'll use either a SOAP or REST login method from the base WSDLs.